# show modal on top of video

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible for modal to be on top of the video element?. My application is something like video tutorial and I put a pop-up question on certain time. It is currently working now but my problem is if the user watching on maximize state the video will pause but it will not appear my modal.

Here is my current modal:

```
 <div id="popQuestModal" class="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
            <form class="modal-content" id="quistionnaire">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 id="popQuestion" style="text-align:center">. . .</h1>
                    <hr>
                    <div id="packageOption1" class="form-check form-check-inline" style="margin-top:20px;">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radOption1" name="choice" style="width:2em; height:2em">
                        <label id="popOption1" class="form-check-label" for="materialInline1" style="font-size:20px"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div id="packageOption2" class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radOption2" name="choice" style="width:2em; height:2em">
                        <label id="popOption2" class="form-check-label" for="materialInline2" style="font-size:20px"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div id="packageOption3" class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radOption3" name="choice" style="width:2em; height:2em">
                        <label id="popOption3" class="form-check-label" for="materialInline3" style="font-size:20px"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div id="packageOption4" class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radOption4" name="choice" style="width:2em; height:2em">
                        <label id="popOption4" class="form-check-label" for="materialInline3" style="font-size:20px"></label>

                    </div>

                    <label id="correctAnswer" style="display:none"></label>
                    <hr>

                    <h3 id="displayCorrect" style="text-align:right"></h3>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Any suggestion/Comments TIA.

Answer (score 0):

change the z-index of the modal to a higher number in the CSS.

Comment: I already tried that but still got same result:  .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 2147483647; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }